How do I render the field lines of a vector field using a fragment shader
So I'm trying to make some electric field lines on the GPU. The electric field function just loops over all charges and adds up the forces resulting in a vector that points in the direction of the field
vec2 field_vector(vec2 pos, PointCharge q) {
    return (pos-q.pos) * (q.charge/distance_sq(pos, q.pos));
}
    

vec2 electric_field(vec2 pos) {
    vec2 field = vec2(0, 0);
    for (int i=0; i<charge_count; i++) {
        PointCharge q = charges[i];
        field += field_vector(pos, q);
    }

    return field;
}

Vector field:

This image is the direction of the electric field vector with just with x=red channel and y=green channel.
How do I render lines in the direction of the vector field like this (in the fragment shader):
charge field lines:

I already tried something like this:
float value = sin(atan(field.y, field.x) * 10.0);

but it was really just trying out random stuff. This formula seems to give the correct result for a field with charges with the same sign, but doesn't work for a field with opposite charges.
